# Invalid conversion from runtime type String to Map<String,ANY>

Tags: error

Can't figure out why I can't cast string to map, here's the relevant code. Thanks! -

```
string f = RESTCallout.sendCallout('callout:Twilio_Schedule','POST', g.twilio_conversation_id__c);

Object RespObj = (Object)JSON.deserializeUntyped(f);

map<String, Object> RespObjMap = (map<String, Object>)RespObj;

The error is on - map<String, Object> RespObjMap = (map<String, Object>)RespObj;
```

The response body is -
"{"+15555555555":{"messageCount":2}}"

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you serialized the JSON in RESTCallout.sendCallout, resulting in a double-serialized object. You should fix the problem there. Aside from that, if you can't change that logic, you can double-deserialize to fix this:

```
map<String, Object> RespObjMap = (map<String, Object>)
  json.deserializeUntyped(
    json.deserializeUntyped((String)f)
  );
```

It may already also be deserialized from the callout method, try:

```
Map<String, Object> RespObjMap = (Map<String, Object>)f;
```

Comment: Hm, I see. I'm getting this error on the top-level deserialize - Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void deserializeUntyped(Object) from the type System.JSON - any ideas?

Comment: @bill Try casting it (edited answer). Failing that, maybe it's *already* deserialized and you don't need to do anything? Try casting it directly from Object f to a `Map<String, Object>` instead.

Comment: @bill No, just as I demonstrated in my answer (edited).

Comment: double deserialization worked, thanks!